# how to use other file array in program

Tags: perl

list.pl

```
my @array1 = qw ( l2  l3 l4 l5 );
my @array2 = qe ( l6  l2 l3 );
```

Pgm.pl

```
use list.pl 

print @array1;
```

is it possible ?

Comment: Not directly. The whole point of `my` is to make it impossible to access a variable outside of its scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html), `require 'list.pl'`.
You might also need to change the scope prefix `my` to something more global.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do something like this, you should setup a module:

`List.pm`:

```
 package List;
 use Exporter;
 our @ISA    = 'Exporter';
 our @EXPORT = qw(@array1 @array2);     

 our @array1 = qw(12 13 14 15);
 our @array2 = qw(16 12 13);
```

`Pgm.pl`:

```
 use List;
 print @array1;
```

But in general it is better to either code this using fully qualified names (removing the need for `Exporter`):

```
 use List ();
 print @List::array1;
```

Or to create an accessor method:

`List.pm`:

```
package List;

my @array1 = qw(12 13 14 15); # my makes these arrays private to this file
my @array2 = qw(16 12 13);

sub array1 {\@array1}  # accessor methods provide ways to change your 
sub array2 {\@array2}  # implementation if needed
```

`Pgm.pl`:

```
use List;

my $array1 = List->array1;

print @$array1;
```